# Javascript/Ajax Request very erratic and random

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been working on the following code and with help from @squint, I have got to a point where it appears to work, but very erratic and randomly.

**Code Edited with @TomasZato suggestions**

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
    <!--#include file="../Connections/DVerto.asp" -->
    <%
Dim Recordset1
Dim Recordset1_cmd
Dim Recordset1_numRows

Set Recordset1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Recordset1_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_DVerto_STRING
Recordset1_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Part_Number FROM dbo.Stock_Header WHERE Part_Number like '84%'" 
Recordset1_cmd.Prepared = true

Set Recordset1 = Recordset1_cmd.Execute
Recordset1_numRows = 0
%>
    <%
    Dim Repeat1__numRows
    Dim Repeat1__index

    Repeat1__numRows = 10
    Repeat1__index = 0
    Recordset1_numRows = Recordset1_numRows + Repeat1__numRows
    %>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="loadDoc()">
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
      <% 
    While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT Recordset1.EOF)) 
    %>
      <tr>
        <td class="prodref"><%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("Part_Number").Value)%></td>
        <td class="demo">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <% 
      Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
      Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
      Recordset1.MoveNext()
    Wend
    %>
    </table>
    <script>
    // This creates array of elements with requested class name - eg. [HTMLElement, HTMLElement ...]
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref");
var outputElements = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
// Allways check if there is correct number of demo elements to print loaded data in
if(elements.length != outputElements.length) {
    console.error("The number of prodref and demo elements is not the same!");
}
// Loop through both arrays of elements and make AJAX request for every one of them
for (var i=0, length=elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    loadDoc(elements[i], outputElements[i]);
}

function loadDoc(element, demoElement) {
    console.log("creating loadDoc() call for element", element);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "data.asp?prodref="+element.innerHTML;
    // Onload calls if request was successful
    xhttp.onload = function() {
       console.log("loadDoc() call for element", element, "succeeded");
       demoElement.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    };
    // Error calls if there is an error
    xhttp.onerror = function() {
        console.error("There was some problem with the request for element",element," with url '", url, "', check the Net debug panel.");
    }
    // Do not make sync requests, that makes page lag. Just DON'T!!!
    xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xhttp.send();
}
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
    <%
    Recordset1.Close()
    Set Recordset1 = Nothing
    %>
```

**Code (Data.asp)**

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="../Connections/PSCRM.asp" -->
<%
Dim rs_proditem__MMColParam
rs_proditem__MMColParam = "1"
If (Request.QueryString("prodref") <> "") Then 
  rs_proditem__MMColParam = Request.QueryString("prodref")
End If
%>
<%
Dim rs_proditem
Dim rs_proditem_cmd
Dim rs_proditem_numRows

Set rs_proditem_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rs_proditem_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_PSCRM_STRING
rs_proditem_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dba.proditem as t1 LEFT JOIN dba.proditem_xtra as t2 ON t1.prodref=t2.prodref WHERE t1.prodref = ? and rber_mi_source = 'M'" 
rs_proditem_cmd.Prepared = true
rs_proditem_cmd.Parameters.Append rs_proditem_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 25, rs_proditem__MMColParam) ' adVarChar

Set rs_proditem = rs_proditem_cmd.Execute
rs_proditem_numRows = 0
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<div class="demo"><%=(rs_proditem.Fields.Item("proddesc").Value)%></div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<%
rs_proditem.Close()
Set rs_proditem = Nothing
%>
```

When the page loads, some results are seen, sometimes returns 2 results, then more. Sometimes it misses a row out.

I have also noticed that on load the data in the third column `<td class='demo'></td>` which is being pulled from `data.asp` seems to change while the page is still loading?

Any help would be greatly accepted.

Comment: Use more modern callbacks for that XHR request - `onload`, `onerror`... I also totally do not understand why do you duplicate the `document.getElementsByClassName("prodref")`. Just get the array of elements and then loop over it. This is gonna slow your page down and is hard to read and understand.

Comment: @TomášZato I am working off a demo found on w3Schools and have limited experience with Javascript and Ajax. Could you expand a little further on the use of `onload`, `onerror`

Comment: Time to move on from ASP surely.

Comment: @JonathanGriffin I cleaned up your code but I think the error is caused by your server script. Still, at least you can take a look at a code that is shorter, faster and easy to understand (IMHO).

Comment: You do not describe the end result that you would like to achieve? What do you mean by "erratic and random"? As for `onload`, please refer to [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). The `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous, which means it can trigger the callback in `onreadystatechange` at any time in the future, which could explain why you see your content changing. Finally, the callback in your `body.onload` calls `loadDoc()` without any argument?

Comment: @Shaun It is! I am just stuck in my way, and it works (I think) for what I am doing. I will set a New Years resolution to move on.

Comment: @ghybs The end result is that a result against each part number held in column `<td class="prodref">` will be displayed in the end column `<td class='demo'>`. What I mean by erratic is random number of rows returned (differs on each refresh), false results, blank rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you produced totally obscure code and you forgot what it's doing. First to the cause - I actually don't understand how come it ever works. First you do this:

```
 a[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref").innerHTML;
```

This is wrong because

1. `a` is `HTMLElementCollection` and is not supposed to be changed
2. `document.getElementsByClassName("prodref")` is an also `HTMLElementCollection` and has no property `innerHTML`

`a[i]` should now contain `undefined`, but since `HTMLElementCollection` array is **immutable** this code just doesn't do anything.

After this, you try to do this - technically it should work, because your wrong code above didn't do anything:

```
 xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?prodref="+a[i].innerHTML, true);
```

But it fails, which indicates there's an error you're hiding from me (eg. problem in the VBS script).

#### Fixed code with remarks

I decided to clean up and comment your code:

```
// This creates array of elements with requested class name - eg. [HTMLElement, HTMLElement ...]
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref");
var outputElements = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
// Allways check if there is correct number of demo elements to print loaded data in
if(elements.length != outputElements.length) {
    console.error("The number of prodref and demo elements is not the same!");
}
// Loop through both arrays of elements and make AJAX request for every one of them
for (var i=0, length=elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    loadDoc(elements[i], outputElements[i]);
}

function loadDoc(element, demoElement) {
    console.log("creating loadDoc() call for element", element);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "data.asp?prodref="+element.innerHTML;
    // Onload calls if request was successful
    xhttp.onload = function() {
       console.log("loadDoc() call for element", element, "succeeded");
       demoElement.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    };
    // Error calls if there is an error
    xhttp.onerror = function() {
        console.error("There was some problem with the request for element",element," with url '", url, "', check the Net debug panel.");
    }
    // Do not make sync requests, that makes page lag. Just DON'T!!!
    xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Of course, since you decided not to provide a good test page, I couldn't test this code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the revised code only generates a result for the first row. My code in `data.asp` is simply a connection to my database, which uses a `Request.QueryString("prodref")` to find the result, and then displays the result. I will try to get a test page setup.

Comment: As I told you, I can't debug the error if you do not provide test case. I revised the code so that it's easier to debug. If you refuse to provide any information to help you **and** brag about how my solution doesn't work you're just shitting on my head.

Comment: I am struggling to find somewhere to host the code and database required. I have attached the code for `data.asp` in my original question.